# What are sub and super classes?

Tags: class

I've been wondering this quite a lot really. I've heard many people mention them but don't know what they actually are. I'm assuming they're the same in all class-based languages (if not, then what are they in Java?).

Sorry for my ignorance but I'm learning Java and my book only explains the basics.

Comment: More and less specified classes respectively. A subclass (child) of a superclass (parent) can (usually) do everything the parent can and contains all the same types of data. But it has more than the parent. A class Tree representing might have data like, for example, age and height, but a subclass might have more specific things. MapleTree might be a subclass, and have extra specific data like "syrup tastiness", or actions like "get syrup" which are not possible with the superclass. The superclass is more flexible and general, the subclass more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclasses extend superclasses. They use some or all of the functionality of their superclass, but also have some unique functionality of their own. Two different classes may extend the same superclass and share its functionality. That way, you don't have to duplicate the code in the superclass to both subclasses.

For example: say you have two classes, a cat and a parrot. They look like this:

```
class Cat {
    private int speed;
    private String name;
    private String sound;

    public void meouw() {
        //make a sound.
    }

    public void attack() {
        //attack some prey
    }
}

class Parrot {
    private int speed;
    private String name;
    private String sound;

    public void talk() {
        //make a sound.
    }

    public void fly() {
        //fly away
    }
}
```

Now, you could do a better job using inheritance:

```
class Animal {
    private int speed;
    private String name;
    private String sound;

    public void makeSound() {
        //make a sound.
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {

    public void attack() {
        //attack some prey
    }
}

class Parrot extends Animal {

    public void fly() {
        //fly away
    }
}
```

You can see in my last example the cat and the parrot both have a speed stat, a name and a sound. They can both use the makeSound() method as well. In addition, each also has its own method.

If you want, you can also override a method from a superclass and add extra functionality.

```
@Override
public void someMethod() {
    super.someMethod();
    //extra functionality...
}
```

The super.someMethod() calls the method in the superclass. If you do this, you get functionality from the super method as well. If you don't do this, the method in the superclass is never executed.

Comment: Thanks. That was a good explanation. It turns out I've used subclasses quite a lot before, just wasn't sure of their name.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with inheritance.

The best way to explain this is through an example:

Consider this `Vehicle` class:

```
class Vehicle {

int doors = 4;
int wheels = 4;
bool rolling = false;

int getDoors()
{
    return this->doors;
}

int getWheels()
{
    return this->wheels;
}

float cost()
{
    return price;
}

bool isRolling()
{
    return this->rolling;
}
```

}

This is a parent class having functionalities that any kind of vehicle can have. Which makes it an abstract class.

Here's a sub class, which 'inherits' the vehicle functionalities:

```
class Honda : Vehicle {
    float price = 3000.0;
}
```

and another brand (this one is more expensive)

```
class Ferrari : Vehicle {
    float price = 987654321.0;
}
```

so now when we say:

```
Honda accord = new Honda();
```

we get a Honda instance.

```
Ferrari spider360 = new Ferrari();
```

They are both sub classes of vehicles, but each has its own properties, but belong to the same parent class `Vehicle`.